# Is prefixes such as di-, tri-, etc. considered for alphabetical order in IUPAC nomenclature?

Tags: nomenclature

The correct IUPAC name of a compound was: 4-(1,1-dimethylethyl)-5-ethyloctane.

my question is why not 4-ethyl-5-(1,1-dimethylethyl)octane?

Are prefixes such as di-, tri-, etc. considered for alphabetical order?
and what about prefixes such as cyclo, spiro? Are they too taken into consideration for alphabetical order?

Comment: Related: [Nomenclature of organic compounds containing complex side chains](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/31166/7951)

Comment: Also note that the preferred IUPAC name actually is 4-_tert_-butyl-5-ethyloctane.

Comment: I understood sir, thanks for the help

Comment: We don't consider di,tri ,etc Just ethyl or methyl ,etc are to be considered